# Can I use apps installed on an SD after resetting my phone?

Tags: sd-card

I'm planning to reset my phone (but not the SD card). After it's done, can I just insert my SD card and use the apps just like before?

I'm using a Lumia 525 running the Denim update.

Answer (score 5):

**No, the apps installed on an SD card will not work after you reset your phone.**

The reason is that apps installed on the SD card are assigned a unique key. That key only exists on that phone, so the apps installed on that SD card will not run on another phone.

When the phone is reset, a new key is generated. And because this new key does not match the old key on the SD card, the apps installed there will not run.

If you are planning to reset your phone, just make sure to [backup all the app data](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff) first so you can restore it later.